# Passing data to view in sailsjs asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, sails.js

I want to pass data to res.view only when I have the data calculated.

Code:

```
followers: function(res, req, next){
    var data = [];
    var me = req.session.user;
    for(var i = 0; i<me.followers.length; i++){
      User.findOneById(me.followers[i], function foundUser(err, user){
          if(err) return next(err);
          followers.push(user)
          console.log(user)
      });
    }
    res.view({
      data: data
    })
}
```

Issue is res.view is rendered before the for loop execution. I have been scratching my head to find a way to resolve this but so for no luck. Please dont suggest me the ajax route because that is something that I dont want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `for` loop in your code; it can be accomplished in one query.  Then when you have the results, you can render the view:

```
followers: function(res, req){
    var me = req.session.user;
    // Use an "in" query to find all users 
    // whose id is in the array "me.followers"
    User.find({id: me.followers}).exec(function (err, users){
        // Don't call "next" in your controller--send a response instead
        if(err) return res.serverError(err);
        // Send the array of users to your view as the "data" var
        return res.view({data: users});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use async.series from https://github.com/caolan/async, you can tell to run the res.view only after the for loop execution is finished.